# Angular UI - using $modal in my service DI makes $modal as undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

In the latest AngularJS and UI-Bootstrap, my below code injects $modal  but it is undefined.  Note, that if I inject $modal into a controller, it works great.

Can anyone suggest why the DI fails to init the  $modal in my below service?

```
angular.module ( 'geRbAuthenticationModule', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.factory ('geRbAuthenticationService',  // service name
  [
    '$timeout',             // dependencies
    '$http',
    '$q',
    '$modal',
    function ( $scope, $timeout, $http, $q, $modal  ) {

      BUG here:  $modal is UNDEFINED

     '
     '
     '
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the string "$scope" dependency in your string list.  So change:

```
['$timeout','$http','$q','$modal',
function ( $scope, $timeout, $http, $q, $modal  ) {
```

to:

```
['$scope','$timeout','$http','$q','$modal',
function ( $scope, $timeout, $http, $q, $modal  ) {
```

The reason `$modal` is failing is because it's last in the list.  Right now timeout is going into scope, http into timeout, etc until undefined goes into $modal.

This is such an easy mistake to make that some folks drop the list of strings from their code and use [ngmin](https://github.com/btford/ngmin) in their grunt script.  [ngmin](https://github.com/btford/ngmin) then automatically deals with the minifier issue this form is meant to solve.  This allows you to not worry about matching up string names to parameters:

```
.factory ('geRbAuthenticationService',  // service name
    function ( $scope, $timeout, $http, $q, $modal  ) {
```